# SASS referencing specific parent selector

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass

I have the following code addressing the currency-field parent selector:

```
.currency-field {
  .ng-invalid & {
    border: 1px solid $color-failure;
  }
}
```

I have several class="currency-field" tags in the html and all of them get referenced by the ng-invalid class even though only one of the fields has the ng-invalid class. I want to modify the above code so that only the .currency-field tag with the .ng-invalid class is referenced. 
I want to put a border on the parent currency-field when the child input tag contains the ng-invalid class.

Comment: The desired CSS is what, exactly?

Comment: In your second line of code (`.ng-invalid &`), `&` will be replaced with the parent selector. This means that the selector in the compiled CSS will be `.ng-invalid .currency-field` (meaning, an element with the class `currency-field` inside of another element with the class `ng-invalid`). This is probably not what you want, see Mike's answer for a solution.

Comment: <div class="currency-field">
       <input class="ng-invalid">
  </div>
Mike's answer does not work because currency-field is a parent selector. I need to access the parent selector

Comment: Ok, so what you're *actually* asking is this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Used JS to add an extra class on the currency-field. Problem Solved.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your syntax if you want to have `.currency-field` tag with the `.ng-invalid` class is referenced (`.currency-field.ng-invalid`)

```
.currency-field {
  &.ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid $color-failure;
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot really do that because the ng-invalid class is set dynamically to the input tag nested into the currency-field tag. Here is how the html looks like:
  <div class="currency-field">
       <input class="ng-invalid">
  </div>

Comment: So you want to put a border on the `currency-field` when the child input tag contains the `ng-invalid` class?

Comment: Yes, exactly Mike. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to do this with pure css ... You should either change your slicing and put styling directly on the `ng-invalid` or use JS to add an extra class on the `currency-field` when the child element has the `ng-invalid` class.

Comment: Used JS to add an extra class on the currency-field. Problem Solved.
Accepted your answer with the additional info. Thanks